# How can I access a local file by giving the local file path using HTML/JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

Let's say I've csv file in my C:/test/tes.csv and I've a text box in html file and paste the above path in text box. I've "Load Data" button near by the textbox. when I click on the button I want to alert the content of the file. Insted of default file picker in HTML/JS, there is anyway to load the data? I want to use it in my application.

Please help me to figure out it

Comment: Can you add your code please?

Answer (score 0):

You should try and use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), which allows you to read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer.

Eric Bidelman wrote [this awesome article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) that can help you get started.